# prove $\rho\in K\to ||\sqrt{\rho}'||_{L^2}^2$ is convex, where $K$ is a convex cone

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

$$K = \{\rho\in H^1(0,1);\rho \ge 0,\sqrt{\rho}\in H^1(0,1)\}$$

I have proved that $K$ is a convex cone. Now I'm asked to prove that $\rho\in K\to ||\sqrt{\rho}'||_{L^2}^2$ is convex.

I tried several ways to compute, but I can only get 
$$||\sqrt{tu+(1-t)v}'||_{L^2}^2 \le 2t||\sqrt{u}'||_{L^2}^2 + 2(1-t)||\sqrt{v}'||_{L^2}^2 \text{ or }\le \sqrt{t}||\sqrt{u}'||_{L^2}^2 + \sqrt{1-t}||\sqrt{v}'||_{L^2}^2$$
So any ideas how to get convexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- Compute $\sqrt{\rho}'$.
- Use this to get a nice (integral) expression for $\|\sqrt{\rho}'\|_{L^2}^2$.
- Prove that $\mathbb R^2 \ni (a,b) \mapsto a^2/b$ is convex.

Comment: yes, my steps are exactly the same as yours, but I'm having trouble to prove the last step

Comment: Which last step? The convexity of $(a,b) \mapsto a^2/b$? Just compute its Hessian.